# 301 Redirect old dynamic URL to new dynamic URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My .htaccess look like as below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^condos-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /fm
/cond_new?r_id=$1&location=$2 [L]
```

The above URL is my old dynamic URL `http://localhost/fm/condos-2-delhi.html`

My new dynamic URL is `http://localhost/fm/delhi/2/condos` and .htaccess has below pattern

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /fm
/condo_new?location=$1&r_id=$2&name=$3 [L]
```

Now i want all URLs of pattern `http://localhost/fm/condos-2-delhi.html` shall redirect to `http://localhost/fm/delhi/2/flavor` with 301 redirect.
where flavor is name of product.

I tried as below but no success

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^condos-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)
/([^/.]+)/?$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in `/fm/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(condos)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)\.html$ /fm/$3/$2/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure this is your first rule below `RewriteEngine On`.

Comment: that worked but i edited my question now as mistakenly i mentioned `condos` in new url but it is `product name` instead of condos. please help

Comment: Edited Question doesn't make much sense since `http://localhost/fm/condos-2-delhi.html` cannot be redirected to `http://localhost/fm/delhi/2/flavor`. There is no `flavor` in your original URL

Comment: so how m supposed to handle this :(

Comment: htaccess cannot query your database for getting `productId to productName`. You need to handle that in PHP code.