# Handling Headers PHP

Tags: php

I am handling cart as below on my website

**Block 1**

```
$rid = isset($_GET['r_id']) ? $_GET['r_id'] : null;

if(empty($rid)) die('r_id is missing');

if(!isset($_SESSION['re_in_ss']) || $_SESSION['re_in_ss'] != $rid) {
  $cart->empty_cart();
  $_SESSION['re_in_ss'] = $rid;
}
```

and i am rebuilding one of my OLD URL in PHP as below:

**Block 2**

```
$url1 = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (false !== strpos($url1,'goodies')) {
$rebuilt_url = "http://www.example.com/".mb_strtolower($urld)."/" . 
$rid . "/" . $string1;
header ("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: {$rebuilt_url}") ;  // redirect to this url
}
```

where `$urld` and `$string1` has been fetched from DB based on `$rid`.

Now problem i am facing is that if keep Order as

**Block 1**
**Block 2**

then cart just works fine and URL is not getting rebuild.

but when i change the order as

**Block 2**
**Block 1**

Then cart gets cleared everytime and only Rebuild URL works fine.

Suggestions please to get both as working blocks. I tried `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()` but in vain.

Comment: Where is `url1` being used? Where is `urld` being defined? As a side note, you should encode a URL if you're using it as a parameter. (i.e. depending on what `urld` is, you may need to encode it before passing it via the URL)...

Comment: @War10ck edited question for `url1` and `urld` is getting fetched from DB as `$urld = $row['column_name']`. `r_id` is already in encoded form. i just want that both blocks shall work as desired.

Comment: are you redirecting to the same domain or the domain changes at all?

Comment: It is on same domain

Comment: @Prix any idea here please?

Comment: @Gags let's see if I understood the case, you have some ugly url with get parameters at it and you want to make it pretty so you use the block 2 to make it pretty when you make it pretty your site doesn't understand the url and lose the parameters hence no session, why don't you try using `.htaccess` to internally receive the pretty URL and converting the parameters internally?

Comment: @Prix i did same but here i am dealing with situation here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062121/301-redirect-old-dynamic-url-to-new-dynamic-url/` and then `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081393/htaccess-301-redirect-htaccess-or-php/`

Comment: If you are still coding the website the simple and common idea is to use the proper URL from the start and the `.htaccess` only to properly send the pretty URL to the proper PHP, its seems to me you're making a whole lot mess mixing both and recursively going around with half-way fixes to get around it.

Comment: But then how will i handle the URLs cached by google crawlers based on old urls